# Trying to remove black fill under lines in billboard.js line chart

Tags: javascript, billboard.js

I am using the same example line chart shown [here](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#Chart.LineChart). However, I have black fill under the lines on my chart. How do I remove the black fill from under the lines. In the documentation under LineChartOptions there it only shows two configurable options, HidePoints and LinePoint. [Here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/BaWpOvq) is my example. The same thing happens to my time series chart. Thank you.

```
var lineChart = bb.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
    ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
    ["data2", 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
    ],
    type: "line", // for ESM specify as: line()
  },
  bindto: "#lineChart"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `fill: none` to the `bb-chart-lines` class should do the trick.

**Add this to your CSS:**

```
.bb-chart-lines {
  fill: none;
}
```

Link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/aggemar/pen/jOBBjVM)

Comment: @martinbshp Great! Happy to help :)